# Meaning of R command system("touch AAA")

Tags: r, distributed

I am watching a Machine Learning Distributed in R and this lines of code appear:
[image]

For what the teacher says, system("touch fin1") will save the document in fin1 when the process has finished.

**Does anyone know where I can find documentation about such function?**

Comment: http://www.linfo.org/touch.html or go to your terminal/shell and type "man touch" and hit enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `system` as an easy way to send commands to a terminal.  The `touch` command (at least on *unix systems) creates a file.  That's all it does really.

So the individual slave sessions create a file on the system.  Why would they do that? So that the master session can easily detect when the slave sessions have gotten past a certain point in their scripts.  The master session is constantly looping looking to see if all of the slave sessions have successfully gotten past that first actual line in their code.

So the answer your question of "Does anyone know where I can find documentation about such function?" is to look at the documentation provided by your system.  For most *unix systems you can go to a command line and enter the command `man touch` or `man {command you're interested in}` to bring up the man pages for the given command.